# How to check SMTP server running on given port before sending mail using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, smtp, smtpclient

I am using SMTP client to send mails in my application. I need to check whether the given SMTP port (587 or 25) is valid and running to send mails in c#.Please let me know is there any solutions.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using(TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
{
    try {
        tcpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        Console.WriteLine("Port open");
    } catch (Exception) {
        Console.WriteLine("Port closed");
    }
}
```